# Problems with TouchGFX, STM32F746G-discovery board and custom touchscreen

Tags: stm32, display, touchscreen, stm32f7, touchgfx

I encountered a problem while modifiying the STM32F746G-Discovery board.

I modified it like this:

- instead of the 4.3" display, I soldered a 5" display (24 bit RGB--> RGB888, 800x480) to the STM32F7 discovery board
- modified the LTDC settings to match the new display (Can there be an error?)
- set the LCD-TFT clock to 38.4 MHZ (according to the datasheet)
- used the touch controller FT5446 instead of the FT5336
- modified the driver code (it's really similar)

Everytime I touch the display, I get some a disrupted lines in the displayed image, but the touchscreen itself works completely fine. After lifting my finger off the display, the displayed image looks like it should.

See the photo I added.

[image]

Has anyone a hint for me, what could be wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would think your LTDC settings are fine, since you say the display displays correctly when not touching. Also, these settings shouldn't impact touch. Could the display itself 
be faulty? Do you have a spare to try?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late answer. I solved the problem. The Display itself was not the problem. The framebuffer was too big for the SDRAM. Stupid mistake.

Comment: Ah! Easy mistake to make when there's no validation on the size. Glad you solved it.